# How do I upgrade from Office 2010 to Office 2013 with a 2010 language pack?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013

I'm running the American version of Office 2010 with the German Language Pack installed (so that Word does proper spell checking for text in German). I've downloaded the installer for Office 2013, and the first dialog I'm presented with is this:[image: dialog for selecting an MS office product]

When I accept the default choice (shown above), I'm confronted with this:[image: error dialog]]

Can somebody tell me how I am supposed to correct this issue?